# Getting count for analytic functions which is inside case

Tags: sql-server, oracle

**I have a query which return record like.**

```
Name   Total_Case_Count   User_Case_Count   P_Count  Rej_Count  PPP_Count    Active_Count

 XYZ        20                  10            05           02       01        02
```

**I'm using below query for this.**

```
     select row_number() over (order by result.USER_NAME asc) as row_index,
           row_number() over (order by result.USER_NAME asc) as SERIAL_NO,
           result.USER_NAME, 
           result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,
           MAX(Total_Case_Count) AS Total_Case_Count,
           MAX(User_Case_COUNT) AS User_Case_COUNT,
           MAX(Pending_Case_Count) AS Pending_Case_Count,
           MAX(Rejected_Case_Count) AS Rejected_Case_Count,
           MAX(Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count) AS Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,
           MAX(Active_Case_Count) AS Active_Case_Count

    FROM
    (  SELECT               
              UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,
              UA.FIRST_NAME AS USER_NAME,
              NVL(PUIA.PARENT_USER_ACCOUNT_ID,C.CREATED_BY) PID,
              COUNT(*) OVER () Total_Case_Count,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) User_Case_COUNT,

               CASE 
                        WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 2 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Pending_Case_Count,
               CASE 
                        WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 4 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Rejected_Case_Count,

               CASE 
                        WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 6 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,
               CASE 
                        WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID In (1,3,5,7,8,9) THEN  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Active_Case_Count

      FROM CASE C 
            INNER JOIN CASE_STATUS CS ON CS.CASE_STATUS_ID = C.CASE_STATUS_ID
            INNER JOIN SSO.PARENT_USER_IN_APPLICATION PUIA ON PUIA.APPLICATION_ID=12 AND PUIA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID=c.created_by
            INNER JOIN SSO.USER_ACCOUNTS UA ON UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID=C.CREATED_BY
            INNER JOIN CASE_PARTY CP ON cp.sso_user_id=nvl(PUIA.PARENT_USER_ACCOUNT_ID,PUIA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID)
            inner join sso.User_In_Types uit on uit.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID 
            inner join SSO.USER_TYPES  ut on UT.USER_TYPE_ID = UiT.USER_TYPE_ID AND UT.APPLICATION_ID=12

      where 
            UT.APPLICATION_ID = 12 and UT.USER_TYPE_ID = 2170 
            and UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = 2187150 
            and c.case_source not in (4)

    ) result 
            GROUP BY result.USER_NAME, result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID
            ORDER BY USER_NAME
```

Please look into column **Active_Case_Count**. it doesn't bring count of status which am passing (1,3,5,6,7,8,9) inside case. It just return count of any single case status.

**Actually this statement is not returning count of all status**

```
CASE 
    WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID In (1,3,5,7,8,9) THEN  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Active_Case_Count
```

Any suggestion really appreciated.

Comment: use WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID  NOT In (2,4,6)

Comment: User_Case_Count +  P_Count + Rej_Count + PPP_Count   + Active_Count = Total_Case_Count so it looks like correct result, could you provide more detail why are you think what results in Active_Count are incorrect?
Also please try solution suggested by me, it suppose to be less complicated and a bit faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
CASE 
     WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID In (1,3,5,7,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Active_Case_Count
```

Instead of:

```
CASE 
     WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID In (1,3,5,7,8,9) THEN  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Active_Case_Count
```

And

```
SUM(Active_Case_Count) AS Active_Case_Count
```

Instead:

```
MAX(Active_Case_Count) AS Active_Case_Count
```

This will calculate you total number of records in statuses (1,3,5,7,8,9)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Sometime we thinks a lot for small small things :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could replace your `case when c.case_statis_id ... then count(*) over ...` statements with the following:

```
count(case when c.case_status_id = 2 then c.case_status_id end) over (partition by UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) Pending_Case_Count,
count(case when c.case_status_id = 4 then c.case_status_id end) over (partition by UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) Rejected_Case_Count,
count(case when c.case_status_id = 6 then c.case_status_id end) over (partition by UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,
count(case when c.case_status_id In (1,3,5,7,8,9) then c.case_status_id end) over (partition by UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) Active_Case_Count
```

It has the advantage of reducing the number of passthroughs your analytic functions are doing, since you now only have two different `over()` clauses, rather than three.

However, I think you don't even need the analytic functions - you're doing a group by in the outer query, so why not do the work as part of that? E.g.:

```
select row_number() over (order by result.USER_NAME asc) as row_index,
       row_number() over (order by result.USER_NAME asc) as SERIAL_NO,
       result.USER_NAME, 
       result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,
       MAX(Total_Case_Count) AS Total_Case_Count,
       COUNT(*) AS User_Case_COUNT,
       count(case when result.case_status_id = 2 then result.case_status_id end) AS Pending_Case_Count,
       count(case when result.case_status_id = 4 then result.case_status_id end) AS Rejected_Case_Count,
       count(case when result.case_status_id = 6 then result.case_status_id end) AS Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,
       count(case when result.case_status_id In (1,3,5,7,8,9) then result.case_status_id end) AS Active_Case_Count
FROM
      ( SELECT               
                UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,
                UA.FIRST_NAME AS USER_NAME,
                NVL(PUIA.PARENT_USER_ACCOUNT_ID,C.CREATED_BY) PID,
                c.case_status_id,
                COUNT(*) OVER () Total_Case_Count
        FROM CASE C 
              INNER JOIN CASE_STATUS CS ON CS.CASE_STATUS_ID = C.CASE_STATUS_ID
              INNER JOIN SSO.PARENT_USER_IN_APPLICATION PUIA ON PUIA.APPLICATION_ID=12 AND PUIA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID=c.created_by
              INNER JOIN SSO.USER_ACCOUNTS UA ON UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID=C.CREATED_BY
              INNER JOIN CASE_PARTY CP ON cp.sso_user_id=nvl(PUIA.PARENT_USER_ACCOUNT_ID,PUIA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID)
              inner join sso.User_In_Types uit on uit.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID 
              inner join SSO.USER_TYPES  ut on UT.USER_TYPE_ID = UiT.USER_TYPE_ID AND UT.APPLICATION_ID=12
        where 
              UT.APPLICATION_ID = 12 and UT.USER_TYPE_ID = 2170 
              and UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = 2187150 
              and c.case_source not in (4)
      ) result 
GROUP BY result.USER_NAME, result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER BY USER_NAME;
```

(N.B.: I am assuming that UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID is the primary key, and that the inclusion of USER_NAME in the group by therefore doesn't change anything.)

ETA: untested, since you didn't provide any sample data for us to work with.